# Bash Script, stdin

Tags: bash, input, arguments

I have a small problem here.

I've written a script, which works fine. But there is a small problem.

The script takes 1 or 2 arguments. The 2nd arguments is a .txt file.

If you write something like `my_script arg1 test.txt`, the script will work. But when you write `my_script arg1 < test.txt` it doesn't.

Here is a demo of my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $# = 0 || $# > 2 ]]
then
    exit 1
elif [[ $# = 1 || $# = 2 ]]
then
    #do stuff

    if [ ! -z $2 ]
    then
        IN=$2
    else
        exit 3
    fi
fi

cat $IN
```

How can I make it work with `my_script arg1 < test.txt`?

Comment: Do you understand how the script currently works?

Comment: What about parsing arguments, like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to change how `my_script` is called, then just let `cat` read from `myscript`'s standard input by giving it no argument:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $# != 0 ]]
then
    exit 1
fi
cat
```

If you want your script to work with *either* `myscript arg1 < test.txt` *or* `myscript arg1 test.txt`, just check the number of arguments and act accordingly.

```
#!/bin/bash

case $# in
   0) exit 1 ;;
   1) cat ;;
   2) cat $2 ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at how the guys at [bashnative implemented their cat](https://github.com/dalhuijsen/bashnative/blob/master/bin/cat) you should be able to use 'read' to get the piped content..

eg. do something like this:

```
   while read line; do
      echo -n "$line"
   done <"${1}"
```

HTH,

bovako